# React and Node Koa App not rendering direct paths

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, react-router, koa

I'm confused as to why I can't access parts of my app by typing in full paths in the url bar.  If I go to localhost:8080 I can move around my app through links, but if I try accessing a state directly, say, localhost:8080/event a blank screen shows up with no errors.  Even more so, all my files show they have loaded on the network tab of chrome dev tools (including my index page)

client router:

```
import React from 'react';

import {Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createHistory} from 'history';

import EventTable from './components/event/eventTable';
import EventManager from './components/event/eventManager';
import Event from './components/event/event';

var history = createHistory();

render((
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={require('./components/app')}>
      <IndexRoute component={EventTable} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={require('./components/auth/signup')} />
      <Route path="/login" component={require('./components/auth/login')} />
      <Route path="event" component={EventManager} />
      <Route path="event/:eventid" component={Event} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

server router:

```
    'use strict'
var members = require('../controllers/members.js');
var auth = require('../controllers/auth.js');
var router = require('koa-router')();
var eventController = require('../controllers/event.js');

  router.get('/api/members', auth.isAuth, members.allmembers);

  router.post('/api/addmembers', auth.isAuth, members.addMembers);

  router.post('/api/addmember', auth.isAuth, members.addNewMember);

  router.post('/api/notify', members.notify);

  router.post('/api/login', auth.login);

  router.post('/api/signup', auth.signup);

  router.get('/api/authcheck', auth.checkToken);

  router.post('/api/createevent', eventController.createEvent);

  router.get('/api/events', eventController.getEvents);

  router.post('/api/fileupload', function *(next) {
    console.log(this);
    yield this.body = {};
  })


  router.get('/api/awsurl', function *(next){
    yield this.body = {url: upload.getUrl()};
  })

  router.get('/', function *(next) {
    yield this.render('index'); 
  })

  router.get('*', function *(next) {
    yield this.render('index'); 
  })

module.exports = router.routes();
```

I'm running react-router 1.0.3 and KOA 1.0.0

EDIT 1:

I know theres a mix of import/require, I'm in the process of converting the app to es6, I've tried messing with this and it doesn't seem to cause the issue.  Additionally, including or omitting the prepended `/` doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: Do any of the component renders trigger, for example the root (/)? Event paths are without leading /, does that change anything?

Comment: Please see the edit 1.  The index renders and I can navigate through links.  The leading / does not seem to make a difference.